# Hack to get system tray applets into the app indicator (without sni-qt)

Tags: indicator, system-tray

According to many the system tray is legacy software that these many do not wish to further support. At the same time many useful applets do not work with the application indicator and there are no future updates in sight.

How can I hack all the system tray applets to show up in the application indicator (without using sni-qt) which doesn't work?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using, this can be done with 12.04 but I'm not sure about 13.10

Answer (score 0):

What applets are you missing?  There's a whole [bunch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/what-application-indicators-are-available) which exist under the "new" scheme.